# Can Ubuntu PC be connected to a Television?

Tags: vga, tv

I have old P4 Computer that I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on, and it works fine when connected to a monitor using VGA to VGA connection.

I tried connecting the PC to my 44inch television using a VGA (from PC) to RCA Component cord (Red, Green Blue).

I've connected the sound card of the PC to the Composite RCA (Red, White, Yellow).

Nothing shows up on the television. It's just black. Not even the booting shows up. I disconnected the composite and left only the component connected. Still nothing.

Should I change something in the Ubuntu settings prior to connecting it to the television, or am I trying to perform something that is impossible?

Should I be using a VGA to Composite instead?

Comment: Does your TV have a VGA connection? use that instead.

Comment: You may have to specify the resolution capabilities of the TV to the xorg server in, say, /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Monitors tell computers what they can handle, but that doesn't happen over a composite or component cable.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. You will need 2 cables, one for sound and one for video.

For Video you will need a VGA to whatever is supported on your TV's end. For example a VGA to RCA cable, a VGA to Composite Cable, VGA to DVI, VGA to S-Video, etc..

I can confirm in my case that VGA to RCA works with Ubuntu using an Nvidia or Intel card. If you have an Nvidia card you need to open `nvidia-settings` and go to the option that searches for new devices. If you have an Intel card, you just need to plug it in and you are done. VGA to DVI and VGA to S-Video also work.

With the sound is easier. I haven't found yet a combination that does not work. Most of the problems are related to VGA to X cable. The only issues you should know is a direct HDMI to VGA will not work. This is because HDMI is Digital and VGA is analog. The only way this will work directly (With the same cable) is if your video cards supports digital output through a VGA port. In any other case you will need a VGA to HDMI converter.