# Ubuntu won't display boot process on component video ("comp out") on TV

Tags: boot

Ubuntu won't boot when I choose "Try Ubuntu without installation" and is connected to the TV via the orange cable aka "comp out", and it boots perfectly fine when it's connected to monitor.

[Picture of the card here.](http://microdream.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img_6048_2.jpg)

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: `"orange" cable aka "comp out"` -  VGA, HDMI, what?

Comment: Can you post a picture of where this cable is connected to the back of your computer? I'm not fully convinced what type of connection to the computer this is.

Comment: http://microdream.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img_6048_2.jpg

This would be the picture of it (first on the left)
The thing is, he starts the booting, and after some time stops with black screen and blinking bottom line.

Comment: You may have to specify the resolution capabilities of the TV to the xorg server in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Monitors tell computers what they can handle, but that doesn't happen over a composite or component cable. More or less a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/175158/can-ubuntu-pc-be-connected-to-a-television.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect a TV through a component video signal, it is is a good secondary monitor, but a lousy primary monitor.

The best thing to do is to hook up *both* the monitor and the TV, configure the TV from the monitor using system settings - screen display as a secondary screen, shut down the computer, remove the monitor and then boot the computer again.

**Disadvantage:** as you're using a component video, nothing of the boot process will be displayed on the TV (BIOS, `grub`, ...) until the video driver loads (login screen) but then it should work normally...

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.